# Apt-get returns several errors

Tags: raspbian, apt, dpkg

I'm a newbie running Raspian (Debian 8 Jessie) and managed to mess up something with apt-get. 
Any advice or hints to fix the errors below would be greatly appreciated!

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  chromium-browser cmake cmake-data debhelper libgl1-mesa-dri raspberrypi-sys-mods rpi-chromium-mods sonic-pi
  wolfram-engine xserver-xorg-input-all
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up raspi-config (20170307) ...
insserv: warning: script 'redis_6379' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service zbw_connect and redis_6379 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service redis_6379 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service zbw_connect at depth 1
insserv: Stopping redis_6379 depends on zbw_connect and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package raspi-config (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rc-gui:
 rc-gui depends on raspi-config; however:
  Package raspi-config is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rc-gui (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 raspi-config
 rc-gui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you recall what you did that could have broke it? Often mucking with the system Python causes this sort of grief. If you can recall the steps you took before it broke, it would help people help you.

Comment: Too many things at once I'm afraid :-/, I tried to uninstall redis with sudo apt-get remove redis but the package was not found so I followed some tutorial removing the files manually.

Comment: Ahh, there is your problem. You should not have done that. Do you recall what you deleted manually? Post a history output on paste.debian.net. Or you could reimage the SD card if there is nothing important on the image.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the Loop warning in the beginning was the solution.
I removed redis_6379 from /etc/init.d and everything started working without errors.

My own lesson: Start trying to fix the errors from the top...

/ Johan

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.